# Deploy YII on Elastic Beanstalk with eb console

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii, composer-php, bower

I trying deploy basic yii application on Elastic Beanstalk. EB's composer install all packages from composer.json, except BOwer, because, as i understand, bower installed by separate command, like described here: http://www.yiiframework.com/download/

php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta3"

I can create .ebextensions witn config file and install my own composer, and then install bower. But question is it a best-practise? Because EB already have own composer.

Comment: i have same problem. did u find any solution?

Comment: Sad, but no. :( I use now common ec2 instance instead eb.

Comment: i found solution here. http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/08/19/solving-the-elastic-beanstalk-composer-deployment-problems/
i chose way that zip all vender and composer.lock file. So no need to run `composer install`

Comment: Yes, or remove vendor from gitignore if git used for deploy. Same way bad practice. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
commands:
    01updateComposer:
        command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update
    02globalrequired:
        command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar require fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.0.0-beta4

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
  option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
  value: /root
```

finally i found solution. composer global require that mean install xxx package at COMPOSER_HOME.
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home

Comment: Great, will try it later.

Comment: I tried this solution but I am still having the same issue where Bower fails to update/install so the all process fails. Any other person with the same issue ?